# MySQL Error : Subquery returns more than 1 row. How can I optimize this query?

Tags: mysql

```
SET @v1 := (SELECT questor.questioncart.idQuestionCart FROM questioncart WHERE User_username = "eamin" ORDER BY idQuestionCart DESC LIMIT 1);
SET @v2 := (SELECT questor.questioncart_has_question.Question_idQuestion FROM questioncart_has_question WHERE QuestionCart_idQuestionCart = @v1);
SELECT questor.question.questionText FROM question WHERE idQuestion = @v2;
```

In this MySQL query I am getting "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error.
MySQL is pointing the second query (@v2) as the error creating one. What I can do to resolve this issue? Can you provide me any optimized mysql for my given query which will solve the problem?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results help much, much more than non-functioning queries.

Comment: Well you could simply add LIMIT 1 – but whether this will then select the value from the actual record (of the multiple ones matching the WHERE criteria that obviously exist) you want, is doubtful …

Answer (score 0):

You either have to use `LIMIT 1` in the query:

```
SET @v2 := (SELECT questor.questioncart_has_question.Question_idQuestion 
            FROM questioncart_has_question 
            WHERE QuestionCart_idQuestionCart = @v1
            LIMIT 1);
```

or, convert the last query like this:

```
SELECT questor.question.questionText 
FROM question 
WHERE idQuestion IN (SELECT questor.questioncart_has_question.Question_idQuestion 
            FROM questioncart_has_question 
            WHERE QuestionCart_idQuestionCart = @v1)
```

It depends on your business rules and actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the query as a *single* query.  Let MySQL do the optimization for you.  At the very least, this saves the time going back forth to the database for multiple queries:

```
SELECT q.questionText
FROM question q
WHERE idQuestion IN (SELECT qchq.Question_idQuestion
                     FROM questioncart_has_question qchq JOIN
                          (SELECT qc.idQuestionCart
                           FROM questioncart qc
                           WHERE User_username = 'eamin'
                           ORDER BY idQuestionCart DESC
                           LIMIT 1
                          ) qc
                          ON qchq.QuestionCart_idQuestionCart = qc.idQuestionCart
                     );
```